# GPIO callbacks throw segmentation fault

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

I am using callbacks to sense obstacles in a small robot. A left sensor and a right sensor. 
Therefore I add an event twice. Now when the callback is called I remove the event and then later add it again.
This works nice if I only do this for ONE sensor
But if I do them twice, the second time a segmentation error occurs.

```
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    import time

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  

    GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  
    GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  

    def my_callback(channel):  
        print("falling edge detected on ", channel)
        GPIO.remove_event_detect(17)
        #GPIO.remove_event_detect(20) 
        do_something()
        GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300) 
        #    GPIO.add_event_detect(20, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)


    GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)  
#    GPIO.add_event_detect(20, GPIO.FALLING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)
```

Without the comments it fails. I am wondering why...

Note: One stranger thing. When run from the terminal the one-sensor programs runs ok (only one sensor) but in the rpi python environment it fails. The two sensor program always fail

Comment: Python and python modules shouldn't seg fault; this implies someone did not catch an error in the base C code -- perhaps a result of your error, but it still should have been caught and indicated with a python exception.

Comment: You mean if you run with GPIO 17 enabled, or GPIO 20 enabled it works? But when you have GPIO 17 and GPIO 20 enabled it crash?

Comment: An error should be raised, but that is moot.  It is not an intended usage.  RPi.GPIO module callbacks are probably best left permanently enabled.  You need to change your code to cope with that.

Comment: @MatsK yeah, when I use only one (for example 17) and I call it from the terminal it works. But when I used both it crash.

Comment: @goldilocks what is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: @joan why is not the intended use? I am trying to not catch more interruptions when I process the callbacks. Like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143842/raspberry-pi-gpio-events-in-python

Comment: @KansaiRobot It's a guess on my part, based on the known features/bugs of the library.  You'd need to check with the author to get a definitive response.

Comment: Apparently it is a known bug in the library (they tried to correct it to no avail). See https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/tickets/136/ (I ll post am answer later with the details)

Comment: @KansaiRobot I don't know; I don't use python.  I was just pointing out that you should not be confused by the segfault, which is the result of someone else's mistake, even if yours triggered it.  Unfortunately that means more 
direct information about your actual error is not being reported.